# How to use HTA to get computer serialnumber

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am trying to create an Admin tools HTA. This is more for learning than anything else. So far I have found everything that I need on here. Right now I am stuck on one piece. I want to collect the serialnumber of a computer and output it into a textbox or textarea. Here is the code that I am trying to use. As is the code will output "serialnumber" to the text box. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
sub ComputerS


set objExec = objShell.Exec("wmic bios get serialnumber")

Set objStdOut = objExec.StdOut
strLine = objStdOut.ReadLine
queryResults.value = strLine

end Sub
```

and here is the code for the texarea and button

```
<input type="button" value="Serial" onClick="ComputerS">
<textarea name="queryResults" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
```

So I figured it out. I had to add one line of code

```
sub ComputerS


set objExec = objShell.Exec("wmic bios get serialnumber")

Set objStdOut = objExec.StdOut
objExec.StdOut.skipLine
strLine = objStdOut.ReadLine
queryResults.value = strLine

end Sub
```

When I added the skipLine it worked perfectly.
Thanks everyone for the help I will definitely be using your information in the near future when I expand on my tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this HTA :

```
<html>
<HTA:APPLICATION
ICON="cmd.exe"
APPLICATIONNAME ="Bios Serial Number"
BORDER="dialog"
BORDERSTYLE="complex"
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
>
<Title>Bios Serial Number</title>
<style>
body{
background-color: Black;
}
</style>
<script type="text/Vbscript">
sub ComputerS()
    set objShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    set objExec = objShell.Exec("wmic bios get serialnumber")
    Set objStdOut = objExec.StdOut
    strLine = objStdOut.ReadAll
    queryResults.value = strLine
end Sub
</script>
<body text="white">
<center>
<textarea name="queryResults" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Get Serial Number" onClick="ComputerS">
</body>
</html>
```

And if you want to get more information about the computer just try this HTA :

```
<html>
<HTA:APPLICATION
ICON="cmd.exe"
APPLICATIONNAME ="Get Info PC"
BORDER="dialog"
BORDERSTYLE="complex"
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
>
<Title>Get Info PC</title>
<style>
body{
background-color: Black;
}
</style>
<script type="text/Vbscript">
sub ComputerS()
    Set oShell = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set env = oShell.environment("Process")
    strComputer = env.Item("Computername")
    Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    Const UnInstPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
    Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_
    ".\root\default:StdRegProv")

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem",,48)
    Set dtmConvertedDate = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

    report = report & "******************************************" & vbCrLf
    report = report & " - Information  de l'ordinateur " & strComputer & " - " & vbCrLf
    report = report & "******************************************" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf


    report = report & vbCrLf & "******************************************" & vbCrLf
    report = report & "Informations sur Windows" & vbCrLf & "******************************************" & vbCrLf

    For Each objItem in colItems
        report = report &  "- Nom du poste: " & strComputer  & vbCrLf
        report = report &  "- Description de l'ordinateur: " & objItem.Description & vbCrLf
        report = report &  "- Utilisateur possédant la licence Windows: " & objItem.RegisteredUser & vbCrLf
        report = report &  "- Organisation possédant la licence Windows: " & objItem.Organization & vbCrLf
        report = report & "******************************************" & vbCrLf
        report = report &  "- Nom du système d'exploitation: " & objItem.Caption & vbCrLf
        If (objItem.OSProductSuite <> "")Then
            report = report &  "- Système d'exploitation de la suite " & objItem.OSProductSuite & vbCrLf
        End If
        report = report &  "- Version: " & objItem.Version & vbCrLf
        dtmConvertedDate.Value = objItem.InstallDate
        dtmInstallDate = dtmConvertedDate.GetVarDate
        report = report &  "- Date de son installation: " & dtmInstallDate & vbCrLf
        report = report &  "- Numéro de série de " & objItem.Caption & ": " & objItem.SerialNumber & vbCrLf
        report = report & vbCrLf
        report = report & "******************************************" & vbCrLf
        report = report & "Détails techniques sur Windows"& vbCrlf
        report = report & "******************************************" & vbCrLf
        report = report &  "- Numéro du dernier Service Pack majeur installé: "
        report = report & objItem.ServicePackMajorVersion & vbCrLf

        If (objItem.MaxNumberOfProcesses="-1") Then
            report = report &  "- Maximum de processus pouvant être ouvert: Aucune limite fixée" & vbCrLf
        Else
            report = report &  "- Maximum de processus pouvant être ouvert: " & objItem.MaxNumberOfProcesses & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next

    Set colBIOS =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
    report = report & "******************************************" & vbCrLf
    report = report & "BIOS - Utilitaire de détection des disques et" & vbCrLf
    report = report & " de gestion des composantes internes" & vbCrLf & "******************************************" & vbCrLf

    For Each objBIOS in colBIOS
        report = report & "- Nom: " & objBIOS.Name & vbCrLf
        report = report & "- Code d'identification: " & objBIOS.IdentificationCode & vbCrLf
        report = report & "- Manufacturier: " & objBIOS.Manufacturer & vbCrLf
        report = report & "- BIOS primaire: " & objBIOS.PrimaryBIOS & vbCrLf
        dtmConvertedDate.Value = objBIOS.ReleaseDate
        dtmInstallDate = dtmConvertedDate.GetVarDate
        report = report & "- Date de création: " & dtmInstallDate & vbCrLf
        report = report & "- Numéro de série: " & objBIOS.SerialNumber & vbCrLf
        report = report & "- Version: " & objBIOS.Version & vbCrLf
        report = report & "- Version (SMBIOS): " & objBIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion & vbCrLf
        report = report & vbCrLf
    Next

    Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
    report = report & "******************************************" & vbCrLf
    report = report & "Mémoire vive (RAM) et processeur" & vbCrLf & "******************************************" & vbCrLf
    For Each objComputer in colSettings
        report = report & "- Vous avez actuellement " & objComputer.TotalPhysicalMemory /1024\1024+1 & " Mo de mémoire vive(RAM) au total." & vbcrlf
    Next

    Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Processor")
    For Each objProcessor in colSettings

        report = report & "- Type de processeur: "
        If objProcessor.Architecture = 0 Then
            report = report & "x86" & vbCrLf
        ElseIf objProcessor.Architecture = 1 Then
            report = report & "MIPS" & vbCrLf
        ElseIf objProcessor.Architecture = 2 Then
            report = report & "Alpha" & vbCrLf
        ElseIf objProcessor.Architecture = 3 Then
            report = report & "PowerPC" & vbCrLf
        ElseIf objProcessor.Architecture = 6 Then
            report = report & "ia64" & vbCrLf
        Else
            report = report & "inconnu" & vbCrLf
        End If

        report = report & "- Nom du processeur: " & objProcessor.Name & vbCrLf
        report = report & "- Description du processeur: " & objProcessor.Description & vbCrLf
        report = report & "- Vitesse actuelle du processeur: " & objProcessor.CurrentClockSpeed & " Mhz" & vbCrLf
        report = report & "- Vitesse maximale du processeur: " & objProcessor.MaxClockSpeed & " Mhz" & vbCrLf

        report = report & vbCrLf
    Next

    report = report & "******************************************" & vbCrLf
    report = report & "Disque(s) dur(s) et autres lecteurs actuellement " & vbCrLf
    report = report & "en usage" & vbCrLf & "******************************************" & vbCrLf

    Dim oFSO
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim oDesLecteurs
    Set oDesLecteurs = oFSO.Drives

    Dim oUnLecteur
    Dim strLectType

    For Each oUnLecteur in oDesLecteurs
        If oUnLecteur.IsReady Then
            Select Case oUnLecteur.DriveType
            Case 0: strLectType = "Inconnu"
            Case 1: strLectType = "Amovible (Disquette, clé USB, etc.)"
            Case 2: strLectType = "Fixe (Disque dur, etc.)"
            Case 3: strLectType = "Réseau"
            Case 4: strLectType = "CD-Rom"
            End Select

            report = report & "- Lettre du lecteur: " & oUnLecteur.DriveLetter & vbCrLf
            report = report & "- Numéro de série: " & oUnLecteur.SerialNumber & vbCrLf
            If (oUnLecteur.FileSystem <> "") Then
                report = report & "- Système de fichier utilisé: " & oUnLecteur.FileSystem & vbCrLf
            End If

            Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
            Set objLogicalDisk = objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='" & oUnLecteur.DriveLetter & ":'")
            report = report & "- Il y a " & objLogicalDisk.FreeSpace /1024\1024+1 & " Mo d'espace restant sur ce lecteur/disque" & vbCrLf
            report = report & "- Il y a " & objLogicalDisk.Size /1024\1024+1 & " Mo d'espace au total sur ce lecteur/disque" & vbCrLf

        End If
        report = report & vbCrLf
    Next

    queryResults.value = report
end Sub
</script>
<body text="white">
<center>
<textarea name="queryResults" rows="35" cols="120"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Get Info PC" onClick="ComputerS">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding the answer I was looking for on my own. The code I was looking for was very simple.

```
objExec.StdOut.SkipLine
```

this was the only thing that I needed to add to get the results I wanted.